cookies not getting set on browser but when I tested backend in postman cookies do get set in postman but when I make api call from fetch
cookies not getting set on browser but when I tested backend in postman cookies do get set in postman but when I make api call from fetch It don't get set in browser I am using vanilla javascript for frontend and for backend nodejs,express.js
[code](https://i.sstatic.net/nyOda.png)

This answer will address your problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
